# Can RSPEC handle theshold test that 90% pass is good enough?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec2

I have a classification function, which determines if a paragraph of text belongs to a category (i.e. it returns true/false). I have an array of real world examples, and I do not expect it classify correctly 100% of the time.

```
def meal?(text)
  !text.match(/restaurant|meal|wine|.../i).nil?
end
```

Can RSPEC specify a test that, when I feed these hundreds of examples to that function, as long as 90% are identified correctly, then it counts as a pass? Even better would be to have RSPEC output examples that fails in the report. If it is possible how can one write such a test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

```
total_correct = 0;
@examples.each do |e|
  match = text.match(/restaurant|meal|wine|.../i)
  match.nil? ? puts e : total_correct += 1
end
(total_correct.to_f / @examples.size).should >= 0.9
```

Anything you can compare, or reduce to a boolean expression, RSpec can handle...which is pretty much everything in software. It's just a matter of figuring out how to express it.

Comment: thanks it works. is there an API way to output incorrect text after all tests are run and be part of the report, be it HTML or console output?

Comment: Not really, but you could write your own output methods that simply log to a file. Depending on what you need, it could be that simple. I'm not sure that really belongs in a unit test, however, since that sounds more like measuring the quality of training, rather than the accuracy of your implementation, but it might be a fit for you.